# TabView is not working inside a ImageBackground

Tags: react-native

I have a TabView inside a ImageBackground in react-native app. The TabView does not show up but it is displayed when given as a parent element.

```
             <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/loginBg.png')} style={styles.container}>
                <TabView
                    navigationState={this.state}
                    renderScene={SceneMap({
                        first: FirstRoute,
                        second: SecondRoute,
                    })}
                    onIndexChange={index => this.setState({ index })}
                    initialLayout={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width }}
                    style={innerStyles.innerContainer}
                />    
            </ImageBackground >
        );

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '50%',

    },
});

const innerStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    innerContainer: {
       flex: 1,
    },
    scene: {
        flex: 1,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reconstruct the headers using the `RenderTabBar` function. I made an example of using the `imageBackground` that you want in the answer.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { TabView, SceneMap } from 'react-native-tab-view';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#ff4081' }]} />
);
const SecondRoute = () => (
  <View style={[styles.container, { backgroundColor: '#673ab7' }]} />
);

export default class TabViewExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
      { key: 'first', title: 'First' },
      { key: 'second', title: 'Second' },
    ],
  };

  _handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({ index });

  _renderTabBar = props => {
    const inputRange = props.navigationState.routes.map((x, i) => i);

    return (
      <View style={styles.tabBar}>
        {props.navigationState.routes.map((route, i) => {
          const color = Animated.color(
            Animated.round(
              Animated.interpolate(props.position, {
                inputRange,
                outputRange: inputRange.map(inputIndex =>
                  inputIndex === i ? 255 : 0
                ),
              })
            ),
            0,
            0
          );

          return (
            <ImageBackground
            source={{uri: "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/07/27/19/47/turtle-863336__340.jpg"}}
            style={{flex:1}}
        >
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.tabItem}
              onPress={() => this.setState({ index: i })}>
              <Animated.Text style={{ color }}>{route.title}</Animated.Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </ImageBackground>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  };

  _renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: SecondRoute,
  });

  render() {
    return (
      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
        onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  tabBar: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingTop: 24,
  },
  tabItem: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 16,
  },
});
```